# How To Find The Slash Index?

Tags: polkadot-js, slashing

My question is: **When there is a deferred slash waiting to be applied, how do you find the INDEX for that slash?** The council can propose a motion to cancel the deferred slash. That form requires the era when the slash happened (easy to find) and the INDEX of the particular slash you want to cancel. I am not able to find the index of the slash in question.

Comment: Using Chain State > Storage > Staking > NominatorSlashInEra I find an example slash for the following nominator stash account with the following numbers: 
      5G1faczTo3Dg7hd8djHJ4GPQAEKZKzhSsaZ4wyFdgsxBczxZ
    1,528,897,666,972,670 (but these numbers do not work in the cancel deferred slash form.) I suspect I might be looking for the slashing span index instead??

Comment: Found it!! On the slashes page in the UI, it is not noted BUT you can guess that the indices start with 0 and each row is numbered as 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.